# Directory.SetCreationTime Error

Tags: c#

Whenever I call Directory.SetCreationTime I get "The process cannot access the file 'C
:\whatever' because it is being used by another process."  The error occurs all the time for every directory.  My program is a C# console app.  This is the simplified version:

```
using System;
namespace test
{
 class test
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   System.IO.Directory.SetCreationTime("C:\\temp", DateTime.Now);
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It is working now.  A virus scan was running.  Duh.
<embarased />

Comment: This can also occur if you have Window File Explorer open to that directory or directories underneath it.  That happens to me on occasion and has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the C:\temp folder open in explorer or cmd.exe or something. I ran your code fine, the opened c:\temp in explorer, ran it again and got the same exception.

Comment: Works on your machine!  The folder is not open in any other program.  For me, the error occur is ocuring all the time for every folder.  There must be some process accessing the whole drive.  Maybe virus software?

Comment: couldn't tell you, maybe are you doing something to open the folder before hand, and not disposing that resource?